# Stop Duplicating Images for every Project in a Solution

Tags: c#, wpf, image

We have a standard company library for our WPF/C# applications.  It has a large set of images.  The library is a separate project in a large solution that has several projects.

When you use an image in these other projects is there a way so they are not duplicated in the projects they are used?  I want them to always go back and reference the image in the library.  I have tried doing the path several ways but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can add the images as a link.

In the target project

1. Click **Add | Existing item...** from the context menu of the root of the project, or a folder in the project.
2. Navigate to the images in your library (select any number of them).
3. Click on the arrow button next to **Add** and select **Add As Link**:

[image]

This will produce a chunk of XML in your target `.csproj` file. You can then change how you want to use the images as usual (e.g. as content, embedded, etc.) Here's an example

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\ClassLibrary1\someicon.ico">
      <Link>someicon.ico</Link>
    </Content>
    <Resource Include="..\ClassLibrary1\someimage.png">
      <Link>someimage.png</Link>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>
```